# Disable video with angularjs and open window when click on it using ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying list of image and videos like table manner.
each cell/block may have image or video.
If I click image, it opens pop up window, there it will display the details of image like description,etc.

so It is working fine now.
Now I want to do the same with video.
that is Video or Thumbnail image of video will display in cell.
when I click on video, it should open Pop up instead of play the video.
Here I will get image/video url through angular element like {{choice.FilePath}}.

For displaying video using angular we can use "Videogular" in angularjs. but it dont have option for ng-click on videos.

could anyone have an idea to achieve this?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. You can use ng-click on any element.

Comment: I want to display thumbnail image of video, when we click it, it should open video in pop up. Is this possible to do in angularjs.